# how get data via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get some data via ajax from a php file:
this my code:

```
jQuery("#load").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'setting/php/get_pic.php'
    }).done(function (data) {
        // Bei Erfolg
        console.log("done:" + data);
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
 $images = glob("BILDER/{*.jpg,*.JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);
 print_r($images);
```

Now I want to write the array, bit I get the whole PHP script code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try. (Eg.)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Ajax Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax(
             {
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'setting/php/get_pic.php'
             }).done(function (data) {
                // Bei Erfolg
                 jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);

                 var img = "";

                 for(i in jsonObj)
                 {
                    img += jsonObj[i]+"<br/>";
                 }

                 $("#jsonParsedResult").html(img);  

            });



});
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="jsonParsedResult"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$images = glob("BILDER/{*.php,*.PHP}", GLOB_BRACE);

echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

Comment: if i try alert(typeof(data)), i get string. But in the php file is a array

Comment: <?php     
 $images = glob("BILDER/{*.jpg,*.JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);
 $images =    array_unique($images);
echo(json_encode($images));?>

Comment: In your PHP file, Comment all current code & try `print_r(array(1,2,3,4,5))` to see whether this array gets alerted. If it's alerting, it means you've some problems with your PHP code.

Comment: my site run on  a local xammp

Comment: i comment all, and only write your code snip: print_r.....
than i tip 127.0.0.1/abc/ss/get.php
and i get
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )

Comment: But there is another Problem: i Write in the done function jquery append( Button). That Means if the Ajax is finesd i want to append an input Button. The Problem is: i can' t set any function by Click. If i Try jquery . Click nothing happens. If i Write onxlick="myfunction". I get the error: myfunction is undefined, but it is defonef. Of i Try the same function at the Beginn, after the document ready snipp, it works. All Tests works Fine, but the same Tests didn't work when i call they with a input Button or input Radio, which i had append in the done function...

Answer (score 0):

In `AJAX` add `dataType: 'json'`

```
jQuery("#load").click(function(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'setting/php/get_pic.php',
            dataType: 'json' //Add this line
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log("done:" + data);
        });
});
```

And in `PHP` end use `die()` or `echo` instead of `print_r()`

```
$images = glob("BILDER/{*.jpg,*.JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);
die(json_encode($images)); //or echo json_encode($images);
```

Comment: i passed it, now i don't get a error, but the result data is empty

Comment: jQuery("#load").click(function(){
  var arr = new Array;
 $.ajax(
        {
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'setting/php/get_pic.php',
       dataType: 'json' 
     })
     .done(function (data) {
      alert(data);// Bei Erfolg
       console.log("done:" + data);
      })
      .fail(function(){
        alert("feil");
      });
        
  });